# Sussing it out᠎

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, metapuzzles

Context: This metapuzzle consists of remixes of puzzles created by my friend sus for a weekly puzzle challenge called One Day One Puzl (1D1P for short). Knowledge of those puzzles is not required to solve this puzzle.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[Imgur album for convenience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epUqV.jpg)

Comment: Oh, I really wish I didn't have to work today...

Comment: ooh, this looks really cool!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Minipuzzle 1

> "In the manner of" in French is A LA. We can see "used to create green colors in fireworks" in the window behind it, and BArium is used for this purpose. Behind that, we have an abbreviation for "STreet" or "STrait"; and in the very back, a screenshot from the show ER. So the answer to this puzzle is **ALABASTER**.

### Minipuzzle 2

> There are two layers on these cells, and correspondingly two ways to fill out the grid:
>  [image: two grid fills]
>  The marked letters spell **NONCE**.

### Minipuzzle 3

> The images on the left side are rebuses for MORSE, PIGPEN, and REBUS. Interpret the right sides appropriately, and you get `ORE`, `GA`, and `NO(-on)`. So the answer to this puzzle is **OREGANO**.

### Minipuzzle 4

> Each of the "clues" here can be interpreted as cryptic wordplay, with spaces removed:
>
>  `h and ymen` = `H+YMEN`
>  `new tonian` = `NATION*`
>  `swallow tail` = `_ALLOW`
>  `draw back` = `WARD<`
>  `s k in head` = `S+K+I_`
>  `st and al on e` = `ST+AL+E`
>  `mid westerner` = `_STERN_`
>  `un in flated` = `FLA(UN)TED`
>  `sound board` = `"BORED"`
>
>  [image: filled grid]
>  The red letters anagram to **FLORIDLY**.

### Minipuzzle 5

> The dots show the middle row of a line of letters mashed together. Since the red lines are 21 pixels long, it follows that the letters we're looking for are directly together, without any spaces.
>
>  [image: image with letters delimited]
>  The only reasonable word that fits this pattern, [according to Nutrimatic](https://nutrimatic.org/?q=%5Bijsxtz%5D%5Bclr%5D%5Bclr%5D%5Bijsxtz%5D%5Bclr%5D%5Bijsxtz%5D%5Bijsxtz%5D&go=Go), is **ILLICIT** (which fits the theme of things being censored!)

### Minipuzzle 6

> The four pairs of squares around the edges each form a mini-minipuzzle.
>
>  The top-left has the truth table for the "implies" operator; the next cell tells us to take the infinitive form, IMPLY.
>  The bottom-right has a diagram of the solar system; using that with the diagram next to it, we get the word STYLE from the bottom.
>
>  The top-right image is a picture of the Fool from the Rider-Waite-Smith tarot deck; the large O is on The WORLD.
>
>  The things being pointed to in the lower left are curly braces; the corresponding tetrominoes spell out SCRUB.
>
>  There are notches in the corners of the outer four puzzles, telling us where in the middle grid they start. You can spell out all four five-letter answers starting with the letter in the corresponding corner, and then making four moves with one of the chess pieces.
>
>  [image: annotated image]
>
>  Once all the letters of the answers are eliminated, the knight is the leftover piece, spelling **GNASH**.

### Minipuzzle 7

> Fill in the digits of pi -- but as *domino halves* rather than directly.
>
>  [image]
>  The indicated regions spell out `DIE SPOT(3)`, which is a clue for **PIP**.

### Minipuzzle 8

> The color codes of the hexagons are: `B1A5ED`, `EFFACE`, `A55E55`, `BAB1E5`, `FACADE`, `DEFACE`, `DEC1DE`, `AC1D1C`, and `ACCE55`.
>
>  We can then use these as clues to fill in the crossword:
>  [image: filled crossword grid]
>  The marked letters anagram to **MISSTEPS**.

### Minipuzzle 9

> The text here spells numbers phonetically in various scripts:
>
>  تھرِ: `t h r i` in Arabic (it should actually be ثرِ to make the "th" sound rather than "t" followed by "h")
>  ֆաիվ: `f ɑ i v` in Armenian
>  зеро: `z e r o` in Cyrillic
>  : `tu` in Cuneiform (specifically Elamite, and possibly others)
>  फोर: `pʰ ɔ r` in Devanagari (the first character should probably have a nuqta under it: फ़ोर)
>  /ˈwən/`:` w ə n` in IPA
>
>  Sorting from 0 to 5, the first letters of each script read **CICADA**.

### Minipuzzle 10

> [image: filled grids]
>  Following the instructions, the leftover letters spell **SANGUINE**.

### Minipuzzle 11

> Each of the rows can have a letter added above the arrow to make a word. In fact, most of them can be completed in two ways:
>  [image: puzzle with letters added in middle]
>  You can make two five-letter words depending on your choice of completion: SIGHT and ORGAN. So the answer is **EYE**.

### Minipuzzle 12

> [image: cryptic clues solved]
>  Solving the cryptic clues and fitting them into the grid, we see **AWARDS** in the middle.

### Minipuzzle 13

> Treating the blocks as a substitution cipher, we get the text:
>  `ACROSS`
>    `PATRIARCH`
>    `CHEMICAL ENDING`
>    `THIS INSTANT`
>  `DOWN`
>    `CROWD NOISE`
>    `COMMOTION`
>    `CONDENSATION`
>  This is a 3×3 crossword, with solution
>  `DAD`
>  `IDE`
>  `NOW`
>
>  Filling the corresponding squares into the grid, we get:
>  [image: picture of filled 3×3 grid with creeper face]
>  the face of a **CREEPER** from Minecraft.

### Minipuzzle 14

> Each of the clues is hiding its clue number, either spelled out (as shown by the eye), or phonetically (as shown by the ear). The answers also have numbers hidden in them in one of these two manners; these numbers need to be condensed into a single square to fit them in the grid.
>  [image: filled grid and annotated clues]
>
>  The circled letters anagram to **CITATION**.

### Minipuzzle 15

> As the example shows, we need to divide the given shape up into letters from the bank on the right.
>
>  The top right need two Os, then the top left needs two Ls, then the bottom left must be a P, and the rest is easy to figure out through trial and error:
>
>  [image: dissected shape]
>
>  The region letters anagram to **LOLLIPOP**.

### Minipuzzle 16

> As shown by the image, we need to figure out the substitution cipher between the letters and the 26 shapes below.
>
>  It turns out each of the smaller shapes is made up of four quadrants, which independently cipher into arrangements of lines:
>
>  [image: correspondence between shapes and quadrants]
>
>  The text at the bottom then reads **CALIPHATE**.

### Metapuzzle

> Each colored box around the outside indicates a property that the answers may or may not have:
>
>  The *pink* box in the top-left indicates "this word has a vowel-consonant-vowel pattern where the vowels are the same": **ALA**BASTER, ILL**ICI**T, CIC**ADA**.
>
>  The *orange* box on the top indicates that the answer shares its first four letters with a US state.
>  The *yellow* box on the top right indicates that the answer has a 4-letter word as a substring.
>  The *green* box on the right indicates an eight-letter answer.
>  The *blue* box on the bottom right indicates that the answer has a 4-letter word as a substring in reverse.
>  The *teal* box on the bottom indicates that the answer starts with C.
>  The *cyan* box on the bottom left indicates that the answer has a consonant-vowel-consonant pattern where the consonants are the same -- the inverse of the red box.
>  The *purple* box on the left indicates that the answer has three copies of a letter.
>
>
>  [image: all words classified]
>  The 1D1P logo in the original image has all eight cells highlighted; we're looking for a word that satisfies all eight of those properties.
>
>  The word in question, and therefore the final answer, is **COLOSSUS**.

<sup>Thanks to Jafe, Stiv, and user39583 for helping me fill in the missing parts of this answer.</sup>

Comment: Immense work, very nice :) A couple of additions for you: rot13(6: PHEYL OENPRF -> FPEHO jvgu funcr-yrggre pbeerfcbaqrapr, naq 10: Gbc yrsg vf npghnyyl CER (abg RER) naq FURRC (Puvarfr Mbqvnp))

Comment: For minipuzzle 7, I think you've mistranscribed the red box. That should fix the issue with the cyan square. :)

Comment: ^ Re 7, rot13(R vf npghnyyl VR juvpu jbhyq tvir lbh QVR FCBG, fb gur 3 yrggre nafjre jbhyq or CVC, fb lbh unir n PIP cebcregl gb pbzcyrzrag lbhe bgure IPI cebcregl, fngvfsvrq ol gur FHF ng gur raq bs PBYBFFHF)

Comment: rot13(Gur beqrevat bs gur yrggref va #15 frrzf gb sbyybj gur beqre bs gur pbybhef va n envaobj)

Comment: Oh, the blue bottom right property is rot13(jbeqf pbagnvavat n 4-yrggre jbeq onpxjneqf: uFNAT, fCRGFfvz, fQENJn, erCRREp, cbCVYYby naq fhfFBYBp (be FHFFbybp))

Comment: and similarly, your last missing property is its complement: rot13(4-yrggre jbeqf sbejneqf: aBAPR, sybeVQYL, ZVFFgrcf (be zvfFGRCf), FNAThvar, nJNEQf, pnyvcUNGR naq pbYBFFhf) although I would personally also have included rot13(YBYYvcbc) in that group, but it seems too good a fit not to be it...

Comment: @Stiv Hm, I also would've included CREE (as well as yours). Nicely spotted, though!